# Elements Exceeding View

Tags: react-native

[image: Screenshot of View]

Hello

I tried creating views in a parent view but the child view keeps going outside of the parent view. What I want is if the space is not enough to accommodate a new View, I want the new View to go to the next line. I do not know how to achieve this as new elements keep showing outside the view

Comment: Did you try setting `flexWrap: 1` on the container?

Comment: `flexWrap: 1` throws an error. Invalid prop expected value {wrap, nowrap, wrap-reverse}

Comment: Sorry, should have been `flexWrap: 'wrap'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexWrap prop
flexWrap: 'wrap'
which will wrap the view inside it
 `<View style={{ width: 300, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }} > {views.map((item, ind) => ( <View style={{ width: 50, height: 20, marginHorizontal: 8, marginVertical: 8 }} /> ))} </View>`